# Need help in posting a Message to my friend's profile Wall in faceBook?

Tags: facebook, ios4

I had implement FaceBook in Iphone using SSO, and posted a message, successfully in my wall, but now my desire is, i want to post some message and pictures and audio to friend's wall, can anyone tell me , How to do this, i had searched the facebook documentation http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/ , in that they had gave the properties, their description and so on, but i donot know how to implement it in my iphone.

i had saw this JSON in garaph API in facebook, but when i tried to pass parameter from Iphone code to this JSON, it gives an error

This is the JSON url

https://graph.facebook.com/19292868552_118464504835613

Error is

> https://graph.facebook.com/%5B1652059207%5D/feed?
>   link=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mybantu.com&description=hi%20to%20all&sdk_version=2&message=Please%20join%20me...&picture=https%3A%2Fwww.mybantu.com%2Fmyphoto.png&name=my%20profile&format=json&api_key=1503895550257
>   8&sdk=ios&access_token=150389555025708%7C2.rQbby0P2QFMRiNOFI1jQSg__.3600.1301158800-100001329298044%7Cq4H0sIHJOPLUTaTWTJ6KX8RdeOA
>   2011-03-26 21:30:27.975
>   FBRecord[5459:207] The operation
>   couldn’t be completed.
>   (facebookErrDomain error 10000.)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is code i tried by Myself,

```
`[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"[friend_ID]/feed" andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];`
```